# Python program to evaluate complicated mathematical alternating formula

Tags: math, formula, nested-loops, evaluation

I have a pretty complicated mathematical formula to evaluate:

[image]

I need to find the values that it throws, and with some graphics analyze the rate of convergence / divergence to extract some conclusions. I have tried unsuccesfully to make a program to do it, but it seems pretty hard. Any help would be really welcomed. Thanks in advance for your time!

(Please find attached below the code where I am currently stuck)

```
@author: juanmoreno
"""

import math

def is_prime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def evaluate_formula(n):
    result = 0
    prime_sum = 0
    prime_product = 1
    log_n = math.log(n)
    prime = 2  # Start with the first prime number

    while prime < n / prime_product:
        if is_prime(prime):
            prime_sum += 1 / (prime_product * (log_n - math.log(prime_product)))
            result += prime_sum
            prime += 1
            
        prime_product *= prime    
    return (-1 / math.log(n) + result)

# Example usage:
n = 10000
result = evaluate_formula(n)
print(f"The result for n={n} is {result}")
```

Comment: Please explain _what part_ you're stuck on, because if you're implementing it the way you are, you can verify each "part" on its own. Is your code not creating the correct summation terms? (create a little "formula string" and print that each iteration to find out). Are your log terms the right ones? (again, print them, find out) Is your summation not correctly alternating signs? (again, print the sign to find out). etc. Don't try to find "the" problem, find _all_ problems, starting small, and working your way up.